# How to Create an XmlSchema instance from a String or an .xsd stored as a resource

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have an .xsd file stored as a resource in my vb.net project.   I need to create an instance of the XmlSchema class using this resource.   Any examples of creating an XmlSchema I can locate do one of the following:
Create the xmlschema by adding elements and attributes manually like [this example](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/XML/Generating-XML-Schema-Dynamically-Using-VBNET-2005-Essentials/).
Create the xmlschema using an XmlTextReader which requires a path to a physical file like [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04x694fe(VS.71).aspx).

Neither of these examples apply to my situation.  I need to create an XmlSchema using either the .xsd stored as a resource or similarly the string that is easily extracted from the resource file.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more digging I ended up with the following solution:

```
Dim xReader As New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(My.Resources.fd.ToString()))
Dim xmlSchema As New XmlSchema()
xmlSchema.Read(xReader, AddressOf ValidationCallback)
```